# JsonUtility in Unity is not working anymore. Why?

Tags: c#, json, parsing, unity-game-engine, json.net

I'm trying to get a integer value from a Json that I GET from a server. I used JsonUtility from Unity libreries and It was working fine. And suddenly it is not parsing anymore.
All values returned are Null.

```
//SAMPLE CODE
SpinResult res = JsonUtility.FromJson<SpinResult>(download.downloadHandler.text);
spinValue = res.result;
//spinValue is always 0. It was working fine


//CLASS
[System.Serializable]
public class SpinResult
{
    public int result;
}


//JSON
{
    "data": {
        "type": "",
        "id": "",
        "attributes": {
            "server_seed": "",
            "client_seed": "",
            "result": 31,
        },
        "next_spin": {
            "hashed_server_seed": "",
            "client_seed": ""
        }
    }
}
```

I just need the integer "RESULT", in this case it should be 31 but the actual output is always 0. I check the Json everytime and its working perfectly fine.

Comment: Is the json text you provided the same as the result of `download.downloadHandler.text`?

Comment: Yes, it is the same Json as a UTF8 string

Comment: Ok. I am trying to reproduce your code, but having trouble getting JsonUtility to work.  That being said, I think the problem is that your class `SpinResult` does not contain the correct properties.  I don't believe `JsonUtility.FromJson<SpinResult>` knows how to convert all that json into a single int.  You probably need to make your `SpinResult'  look more like the json.

Comment: You mean add and arrange the excuded info? I'll try that. What I do not understand is why It was working this way.

Comment: That was the issue, you were right. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this, but try making your class look like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class SpinResult
{
    public string type;
    public string id;
    public Attributes attributes;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Attributes
{
    public string server_seed;
    public string client_seed;
    public int result;
}
```

Then to get the value of `result` you would use:

```
int spinValue = res.attributes.result;
```

Comment: Ok Thanks! That made it.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Would you mind marking this as the correct answer? Thanks!